# bbpress if spectator role - echo out text

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

I'm using bbpress with Wordpress and I'm trying to change how `user-profile.php` inside `wp-content/plugins/bbpress/includes/users/` appear.

I want to echo out a text saying "You do not have permission to participate in the forum" if the user has the spectator role, but I can't accomplish it. This is what I have now:

```
 <p class="bbp-user-forum-role"><?php  printf( __( 'Forum Role: %s',      'bbpress' ), bbp_get_user_display_role()    ); ?></p>
    // My php code comes here:
 if( bbp_get_spectator_role() ) {
    echo "<p>You do not have permission to participate in the forum.</p>";
    }
```

The above doesn't work. However, there is a function called "bbp_is_user_keymaster()". It would be great if there was a similar but `bbp_is_user_spectator()` instead, but I can't seem to find one.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of editing you should be able to use this code: http://simplysmartmedia.com/2013/03/role-based-profile-fields-in-wordpress/

The edited code could look something like;

```
    <?php
function check_user_role( $role, $user_id = null ) {
  if (isset($_REQUEST['user_id']))
    $user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
// Checks if the value is a number
  if ( is_numeric( $user_id ) )
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    else
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
  if ( empty( $user ) )
    return false;
  return in_array( $role, (array) $user->roles );
}

function one_random_test() {
if ( check_user_role ('spectator') ) {
    echo 'You are not allowed to edit anything.';
}
}
  add_action('bbp_template_before_user_profile', 'one_random_test');
?>
```

The text "You are not allowed to edit anything." then appears at the top of the users profile page. Use whatever hook you like to have it appear somewhere else.